# The values added don't show on Gridview? C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm new to the programming world and Stack Overflow, so please forgive the 'noob' question.

I have this method here (linked to Windows form) and the idea is to add information to the Text boxes and have it added to both the Gridview and the database. The problem is that only one part(the ID which is Auto generated) of the information added is being displayed back on the (the ID)

```
 private void btnAddNewAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(txtAdminFname.Text == string.Empty || txtAdminLname.Text == string.Empty ||
                  txtPassword.Text == string.Empty))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: all the boxes have to be filled and try again.");
            }
            // Here it will ADD a new Admin based on the information entered in the form, the New ID for the Admin is generated by the program.
                try
                {
                using (Hawthor_HS_Entities db = new Hawthor_HS_Entities())
                {
                    Administrator addAdministrator = new Administrator();// currently adding only the AID and nothing else.
                    {
                        addAdministrator.FName = txtAdminFname.Text;
                        addAdministrator.LName = txtAdminLname.Text;
                        addAdministrator.Password = txtNewPass.Text;
                    }

                        db.Administrators.Add(addAdministrator);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        DataGridLoad();

                        MessageBox.Show("Success! New Administrator was Added");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not Add new Administrator. Please try again.");
                }
            }
```

I've got an "Edit" method too which seems to work just fine once that row is created (with just the ID).

Here is the DataGridLoad()

```
private void DataGridLoad()
        {
            using (Hawthor_HS_Entities db = new Hawthor_HS_Entities())
            {
                // Loads information into the DataGridView from the Administrators db.
                var adminLIST = (from c in db.Administrators
                    select new
                    {
                        AID = c.AID,
                        FirstName = c.FName,
                        LastName = c.LName
                    }).ToList();

                ADDdataGridView.DataSource = adminLIST;


                // loads information into the AdminID combo box in the EDIT tab.
                cboAdminID.DisplayMember = "AID";
                cboAdminID.ValueMember = "AID";
                cboAdminID.DataSource = adminLIST;

                //loads information into the AID combo box in the DELETE tab.
                cboAID.DisplayMember = "AID";
                cboAID.ValueMember = "AID";
                cboAID.DataSource = adminLIST;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can able to get the ID from the model class once after `SaveChanges()` executed.. In your case, you can get the ID from `addAdministrator` object like `addAdministrator.ID`

Comment: Are the Fname,Lname and password fields written to de Database?

Comment: You used db.Administrators.Add(addAdministrator); for adding, did you try this db.AddToAdministrators(addAdministrator);, Have you seen this option after db?

Comment: 'Are the Fname,Lname and password fields written to de Database?' - yes.    'db.AddToAdministrators(addAdministrator);' does not come up after db. "InsertOnSubmit" does not show either ( i saw this option here on stackflow a while back but could not make work)

Comment: so it seems that you have issue to view record in your datagrid? am i right @Joubert, according to your last comment , your data is properly inserted in table .... please clear this

Comment: yes..from what the little i understand, the data adds just fine to the database but only the ID is shown on the datagrid. once that row is there i can edit and delete it as i expect it to...  is there more info i can provide to help out? cheers for the help so far

Comment: yes please edit your question and add " DataGridLoad(); " detail. @Joubert

Comment: I guess your problem then must be in your DataGrid columns definition or in your Binding. Show us the DataGridLoad method and the DataGrid definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment that you get data successfully in your database but you have an issue to load data properly,  so

Let me share an example , may be it will help you. if not then let me know,

you can use following code to load your `datagridview`

```
var context=new Hawthor_HS_Entities();
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
bi.DataSource = context.Administrators;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bi;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able to get the `ID` from the model class once after `SaveChanges()` executed.. In your case, you can get the `ID` from `addAdministrator` object like

```
try
{
    using (Hawthor_HS_Entities db = new Hawthor_HS_Entities())
    {
        Administrator addAdministrator = new Administrator();// currently adding only the AID and nothing else.
        {
            addAdministrator.FName = txtAdminFname.Text;
            addAdministrator.LName = txtAdminLname.Text;
            addAdministrator.Password = txtNewPass.Text;
        }

        db.Administrators.Add(addAdministrator);
        db.SaveChanges();
        DataGridLoad();
        int Id = addAdministrator.ID; // you can able to get the id for the record you attempt to save.
        MessageBox.Show("Success! New Administrator was Added");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not Add new Administrator. Please try again.");
}
```

Comment: I don't thing this has anything to do with OP problem, as the problem is that Fname,Lname and Password are not being saved, if i understand OP question

Comment: ah yes... sorry about that, i should have been a little more clear... yes its the Fname,Lname and Password that i want to be displayed... the ID already shows... sorry